# how do you specify field dependencies in an XML Schema?

Tags: xsd

This is more of an generic XML Schema question, but if and how do you specify
field dependencies in an XML Schema. For example, how would I say fieldB is
required, if fieldA is provided ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fake this using <choice> and/or <sequence>. For example, you could allow either nothing, fieldB, or fieldA and fieldB, but not just fieldA. This could lead to duplication, which you could prevent by defining a complexType.

Answer (score 0):

Your options for this kind of thing depend on how the 'fields' are represented in XML and on which version of XSD you're using.

If `fieldA` and `fieldB` are elements, including some structure of the following form in the appropriate content model would do the trick.

```
<sequence minOccurs="0">
  <element ref="tns:fieldA" minOccurs="0"/>
  <element ref="tns:fieldB"/>
</sequence>
```

(The two element references can appear in the other order if you prefer.)  It's not clear to me why Erik Hesselink worries that this may lead to duplication, or what form of duplication he's worried about.

If you make `fieldB` be an element and `fieldA` be an (optional?) attribute on that element, the co-occurrence constraint you want follows automatically.

If you make them both attributes, the co-occurrence constraint cannot be enforced by XSD 1.0; some people have recourse to Schematron to handle things like that.  In XSD 1.1 the options for enforcing the constraint in this situation include `xs:assert` and conditional type assignment.